# LLVM: How to use LoopInfoPass and ScalarEvolutionPass in CallGraphSCC-Pass?

Tags: llvm, static-analysis, klee

I want to use `LoopInfoPass` in the `runOnSCC()` method of a pass derived from CallGraphSCC-Pass. More specifically, I want to judge whether a basicblock is in a loop or not in the `runOnSCC()` method.
So, the code should be like:

```
LoopInfo &lf = getAnalysis<LoopInfo>(F);
Loop *bbLoop = lf.getLoopFor(BB);
```

and the getAnalysisUsage:

```
void AnalyzerPass::getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &Info) const {
    Info.addRequired<CallGraphWrapperPass>();
    Info.addRequired<LoopInfo>();
    Info.addRequired<ScalarEvolution>();
    Info.addPreserved<CallGraphWrapperPass>();
    Info.setPreservesCFG();
}
```

and the Initialization:

```
INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(AnalyzerPass, "analyzer",
                      "analysis", false, false)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(CallGraphWrapperPass)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(LoopInfo)
INITIALIZE_PASS_DEPENDENCY(ScalarEvolution)
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(AnalyzerPass, "analyzer",
                    "analysis", false, false)
```

Finally, I use a PassManager:

```
PassManager pm;
pm.add(LoopInfo);
pm.add(ScalarEvolution);
pm.add(AnalyzerPass);
pm.run(&module);
```

When executing the `pm.run(&module)`, I get the error:

```
Unable to schedule 'Natural Loop Info' for 'analysis'.
Unable to schedule pass.
```

I want to ask where am I wrong? There are too little information about how to use CallGraphSCC-Pass. Any help would be much appreciated!